# Rescaling axes with animation in the matplotlib package in Python

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I'm having some trouble getting my axes to autoscale dynamically with my animation using matplotlib.animation in python. Below is an except from my code:

```
def _update_plot(i,fig,scat):
    ax.relim()
    ax.autoscale_view()
    scat.set_offsets(np.array([x[i],y[i]]))
    return scat,

fig = plt.figure()

ax=fig.add_subplot(111,autoscale_on=True)
ax.grid()

x=[x0]
y=[y0]
vx=[vx0]
vy=[vy0]
for t in range(10000):
    PV=getPV(x[-1],y[-1],vx[-1],vy[-1])
    x.append(PV[0])
    y.append(PV[1])
    vx.append(PV[2])
    vy.append(PV[3])

scat = plt.scatter(x=x0,y=y0,c=('r','b','r'))
scat.set_alpha(0.8)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,_update_plot,fargs=(fig,scat),frames=10000,interval=100)

plt.show()
```

`relim` seems only to reset the limits to very tiny default limits of 0.05 to -0.05. Any advice on how to get the axes to rescale appropriately with each update would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Several questions: 1) what is `axes`? should that be `ax? 2) it seems that you always only  set one value in `set_offsets`, it that really the behavior that you want?

Comment: Oh woops. Yes that's supposed to be ax.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! The previously problem is still there though? Any advice?